# Android ViewPager save previous page on onPageSelected

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-webview, viewpagerindicator

I have a ViewPager with pages of WebView. A page has a text field allowing the user to type in contents. I'd like to save the page's input text to a Java variable when moving between pages (by sliding forward/backward).

Unfortunately, it seems onPageSelected only tells me the page number that is about to display, and not the page it came from, which means I can't tell which page I needed to save at the time when the user changes page.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can store the last known page index in a field at the end of `onPageSelected` (initialize it with an appropriate default when your activity starts). Then, inside `onPageSelected`, you check that field to see what page the user was previous on.

```
private int mLastPage;

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // save the information from the page at mLastPage

    mLastPage = position;
}
```